# How is an MD5 or SHA-X hash different from an encryption?

Tags: encryption, hash, cryptography, md5, message-digest

I've read a couple times that MD5 is not an encryption, e.g. on [MD5 ... Encryption?](http://www.md5.net/encryption.php) or [Command Line Message Digest Utility](http://www.fourmilab.ch/md5/).

Well, I get that it's a hash/message digest, and the explanation in the links above says an encryption has to have a key, while hash/md is a *cryptographic* hash function that produces just a signature.  I don't really understand the difference.  Couldn't you see the cryptographic hash function / algorithm as a key?

Also, what is the difference between something that's cryptographic and something that's encryption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't "decrypt" a md5 hashed function, and you chose a bad algorithm if you want to transmit information and the receiver can't read it.

So encryption must be decryptable. MD5 is a "cryptographic" hash function, because it's very difficult to produce a block of information that has a specific given hash value.
So if you want to sign a message, it is enough to sign the hash. This uses less computing power and the receiver can regardless be sure that the original message is untouched.

Comment: ah okay.  so you're saying that by definition, an encryption must be decryptable, whereas something cryptographic is just a consistent obfuscation.  is that right?

Comment: Something "cryptographic" isn't really defined. They mean something that can be used in cryptographic use cases. It doesn't have to be an obfuscation but can also be an encryption.

Answer (score 2):

A hash algorithm causes information about the original data to be lost irreplaceably, whereas an encryption algorithm has a corresponding decryption algorithm which restores the original data.

This can be shown in that hash algorithm results have a uniform size (128, 160, 256, etc. bits) regardless of the input, whereas encryption algorithm results have a variable size depending on the size  of the input.

Comment: heinzi was first and answered both parts, bu +1 for the latter part of your answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can regard the function itself as a key.
Because a key is something you pass to the function in order encrypt or decrypt (<- impossible with md5) a message.